# Is it allowed to change entities' relationship state in Hibernate Interceptor?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have an entity that has a Set of child entities. Can I add/remove some of the children in the collection in Hibernate's `org.hibernate.Interceptor.onFlushDirty()`?

The documentation ([javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/), [JBoss userguide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events)) doesn't explicitly mention changing relationship state, so I just want to make sure it's legitimate.

**Update**

Decided to describe by problem.

There's a `Parent` entity that has a `Set` of `Child` entities. The `Child` entities are created based purely on fields of the `Parent` entity, no additional information needed. The children need to be updated each time before persisting the `Parent`.

I wanted to do it in `Interceptor.onFlushDirty()` by clearing existing children and adding new reclaculated (i.e. `Transient`) children, but I'm getting the `TransientObjectException`. As I understand, it's because I add transient Child entities during flush, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I wouldn't do it, but what is your use case? Maybe you can use a different approach.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov, I've added a description of my problem to the post.

Comment: Clearing and re-adding is not going to work. You will have to update the existing objects.

Comment: Even if I set `CascadeType.ALL` for the `Child` entities?

Comment: I don't know. You will have to try it out. Why can't you update the existing children?

Comment: I sure try it out, but even if it works now I need to know I won't get surprises in the future. Why I think it might not be allowed is because for example it's not allowed for JPA callbacks (`@PrePersist` etc)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't tell you that. You will have to look into the code if you want to know whether this is currently supported. If you want to make sure this stays this way, you would have to participate in Hibernate and ensure there is a test case that ensures this behavior.